# Writing length foldr with function composition

Tags: haskell, function-composition

I would like to rewrite

```
foldr (\_ y = y + 1) 0
```

using `flip`, `const` and `(+1)` and function composition.

I've gotten this far:

```
foldr (\x -> ((+1) . (flip const x)) 0
```

But I can't seem to ditch this lambda. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that `(\_ -> e) = const e`, and here `e = (\y -> y + 1) = (+1)`. Therefore,

```
foldr (const (+1)) 0
```